# Selenium Webdriver testing(Safari ) in windows or ubuntu

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, webdriver

I working on the automation script using selenium webdriver, I tried with the browsers chrome and firefox in my windows and linux machine both chrome and firefox works fine, but I tried the same with safari but it is not working in both windows and linux machine, Wanna know is there a possibility to launch safari webdriver for testing in windows and linux machine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Safari is only available for MacOS, no Sign of any ports. my suggestions are - 1. Run it in Github Actions as MacOS (Free but 7x build minutes per minute). 2. use Virtual Box or a similar tool and boot up a hackintosh instance and run it there. 3. use a cloud MacOs platform.